# Inserting Data from .txt file into SQL DB getting Error Saying no permissions OpenRowSet()

Tags: sql, sql-server, vbscript, permissions, asp-classic

I am stuck with an issue that I am failing to overcome and there has to be a simple explanation. I would greatly appreciate any assistance.

We have a DB server (DB01) and a Web server (Web02). On Web02 we have a VBScript page that looks inside of all Agency Folders on Web02 and finds new .txt files that were sent to use from a 3rd party. We are using a Stored Procedure to complete an insert of the data in the comma delimited file into the Database on DB01. For a while, this worked just fine, but now we are having some issues. We are not sure if a permission has changed or what, but we know that the text file is being read just fine and that when I copy the Insert command into my local SSMS and execute it, it will insert with no issues, so the command is also fine. 
There seems to be an issue on when the DB01 runs the Insert as if it cannot read the file. This is the error that we receive:

```
Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 error '80040e14'

Cannot process the object "SELECT * FROM [Edit Error Management Report_3008963.txt]". The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" indicates that either the object has no columns or the current user does not have permissions on that object.

/billing/EditErrors_ProcFiles.asp, line 319
```

Here is the Insert Command that we can use locally and it works:

```
INSERT INTO RealMedEditErrors (AgencyID, BatchName, DateofService, ErrorDesc, ErrorNumber, MajorCategory, MinorCategory, PatientControlNumber, PatientName, PayerName, RealMedClaimID, RenderingProvider, StatusInEE, SubmissionDate, TotalCharges, ClaimInstanceID) 
SELECT 200, [Batch Name], [Date of Service], [Error Description], [Error Number], [Major Category], [Minor Category], [Patient Control #], [Patient Name], [Payer Name], [Availity Claim ID], [Rendering Provider Name], [Status in EE Mgmt], [Submission Date], [Total Charges], [Claim Instance ID] 
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Text; Database=\\INTEG2-WEB02\EDIGateways\DEV\Availity\AgencyName\Reports\Queue\;HDR=Yes;','SELECT * FROM [Edit Error Management Report_3008963.txt]') 
WHERE NOT ([Batch Name] IS NULL)
```

Here is the Stored Procedure:

```
USE [checkpoint_dev]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_InsertEditError] 
     @AgencyID Int,
     @FileName varchar(150),
     @UnityDir varchar(150)


AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN

INSERT INTO AppLog (Msg, FileName, Comments) VALUES (@AgencyID, @FileName, @UnityDir);

Declare @sql nvarchar(max)

Set @sql='INSERT INTO RealMedEditErrors (AgencyID, BatchName, DateofService, ErrorDesc, ErrorNumber, MajorCategory, MinorCategory, PatientControlNumber, PatientName, PayerName, RealMedClaimID, RenderingProvider, StatusInEE, SubmissionDate, TotalCharges, ClaimInstanceID)';

SET @sql = @sql + ' SELECT '+CAST(@AgencyID AS NVARCHAR(10))+', [Batch Name], [Date of Service], [Error Description], [Error Number],  [Major Category], [Minor Category], [Patient Control #], [Patient Name], [Payer Name], [Availity Claim ID], [Rendering Provider Name], [Status in EE Mgmt], [Submission Date], [Total Charges], [Claim Instance ID]';

SET @sql = @sql + ' FROM OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',
''Text;Database=\\INTEG2-WEB02\EDIGateways\Dev\Availity\'+@UnityDir+'\REPORTS\Queues\;HDR=Yes;'',
''SELECT * FROM ['+@FileName+']'')';

 Exec(@sql)

    END
END

GO
```

Here is the trigger that fires the Stored Procedure that is located within the VBScript page that handles the .txt file:

[image]

Here are images of the Security Settings for our Web02 Folders that have the .txt files:

[image]

The same Security is set for all children folder which is where the files are ftp'd.

Any help on this would be wonderful... 
It may have something to do with the openrowset, it may have been some crazy overlooked permissions, but we are stuck.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the examples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#examples) to make sure your syntax is correct.

I had a similar problem recently. I fixed this by changing my files location to the public folder on my computer.

i.e: `C:\Users\Public\Your_Path`, and using that path in the `OPENROWSET()` call.

**Public** folder should be available to **all users**.

If you still get a permission error, your problem might be with your syntax or file.

Comment: I am going to try placing it into the public folder just as a test and see what that does. I will report back shortly. Thanks!
Edit: As far as the Syntax, this worked yesterday, but the permissions have changed (or at least we think) which is why i am almost certain that it is not code related. I could be very wrong, but that is where my deduction has lead me.

Comment: Ok so i just noticed something very weird... In path is as follows"
INTEG2-WEB02\EDIGateways\Dev\Availity\'+@UnityDir+'\REPORTS\Queues\


When I place the .txt files in the Reports folder and change the Stored Procedure to have 
INTEG2-WEB02\EDIGateways\Dev\Availity\'+@UnityDir+'\REPORTS\

and leave the web page to point to

INTEG2-WEB02\EDIGateways\Dev\Availity\'+@UnityDir+'\REPORTS\Queues\

while the file is also in that directory, it will work just fine... But if it is only inQueues, it will not work and have the error from the main post. permissions are identical.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong here, but it does not look to me like you ever set `@UnityDir` or `@FileName` to any specific values, so your `@sql` variable may be coming back looking something like this:

```
INSERT INTO RealMedEditErrors (AgencyID, BatchName, DateofService, ErrorDesc, ErrorNumber, 
MajorCategory, MinorCategory, PatientControlNumber, PatientName, PayerName, RealMedClaimID, 
RenderingProvider, StatusInEE, SubmissionDate, TotalCharges, ClaimInstanceID) 
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
'Text;Database=\\INTEG2-WEB02\EDIGateways\Dev\
Availity\\REPORTS\Queues\;HDR=Yes;',
'SELECT * FROM []')
```

It's possible you may have done something with your in-house procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_InsertEditError] 
     @AgencyID Int,
     @FileName varchar(150),
     @UnityDir varchar(150)
```

This only raises more questions for us. But what @Guillaume Gillard said is a good place to start.

Comment: Please see my updated Post to see where those values are coming from. I forgot to add that part. Thanks!